# Код не работает

Tags: python-3.x

код должен при введении числа выводить четные числа в порядке убывания от этого числа. При вводе любого числа он пишет это число один раз и всё

```
i=int(input("Введите число"))
while i>=0:
if i%2==0:
    print(i)
    i=i-1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не питонщик и, если я не прав, удалю свой ответ. Но, кажется, должно быть так:

```
i=int(input("Введите число"))
while i>=0:
    if i%2==0:
        print(i)
    i=i-1
```

Т.к. табуляция используется для определения блоков кода ваш вариант видит пустой while(без команд внутри) и игнорирует его, и сразу за ним единственный if. Заверните if внутри while, добавив уровень табуляции

Comment: неправильно. последняя строка `i = i - 1` должна быть на 1 таб левее

Comment: Логично, поправил

Comment: Пустой while не игнорируется, а вызывает ошибку